In The Magicians trilogy, why do various gods want to take people's "humanity"?
Major spoilers for The Magicians book trilogy ahead
I noticed a few parallel stories in which a human makes a Faustian-style bargain for godlike powers: Martin with Umber (willingly), Julia with Reynard the Fox (unwillingly), and (to some extent) Alice becoming a niffin.
There are hints to this idea that these gods want something from them, i.e. their "humanity". Why? What do the gods get out of this bargain?

Alice did not become a niffin through the agency of a god?

@Lexible Yup, I guess that one is an outlier, but still an example of someone attaining godlike powers in exchange for their humanity. (Plus, I have a pet theory... that they are doing this via the "old gods", i.e. the silver giants.)
